# Figures, equations, tables, and algorithms all pop over the top and bottom margins

Tags: vertical-alignment, ieeeconf

I'm working on a paper for a conference which uses the IEEE conference style.  They provide  an ieeeconf.cls file that's supposed to automatically handle the formatting.  However, I find that any figures, tables, algorithms, or equations that wind up at the top or bottom of a page skip over the defined margins.  The online submission platform processes the pdf I submit and gives back a pdf that makes this clear, showing grey boxes defining the region that is within the margins on each page, and in each case these various objects project a few millimeters above or below the margin, while the main text stays within the margins.

Here's a minimal working example I put together:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out if you need a4paper

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
% the lipsum package is only used to generate placeholder text for this example
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\begin{equation}
    C_o(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{R}) = \frac{\sum_{r \in \mathcal{R}} t_r}{S}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    C_p(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{R}) = \frac{\sum_{i,j} D_{ij}t_{\mathcal{R}ij}}{\sum_{i,j} D_{ij}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:cost_fn}
    C(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{R}) = \alpha C_p(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{R}) + \beta C_o(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{R}) + \gamma C_c(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{R})
\end{equation}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[tb]
  \centering
  \framebox{\parbox{2.5in}{
  \includegraphics[scale=0.315]{figs/routes_on_small_graph}
  }}
  \caption{\lipsum[6]}
  \label{fig:example_graph}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[7]

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{An Algorithm}\label{alg:assembleroute}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State {\bfseries Input:} a value $\mathcal{C} = (\mathcal{N}, \mathcal{E}_s, D)$ \
\State $x \leftarrow []$
\State return $x$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[7-16]

\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \caption{A table}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
        a & b & c \\
        \midrule
        a & b & c
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[7-12]

\end{document}
```

For the above to show the results I get, you'll also need the ieeeconf.cls file, which can be found here: https://www.ieee-ras.org/publications/ra-l/information-for-authors-ra-l

If you want, you can view this example in context with its compiled result on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/zvjzcpkvcnpm

In this example, the various "objects"* (an equation, figure, algorithm, and table) project above or below the relevant margins, which is evidenced by the fact that it projects beyond the main text in the opposite column.  This is a problem as the conference's submission guidelines specify that all figures and tables must appear at the top or bottom of a page.

I've tried using \vspace to control the placement of these objects, forcing them into the right position, and that helps with figures but not with the other entity types.  I would appreciate any help in resolving this.

*Is there a proper general term for these entities in latex?  "Floats" wouldn't seem to include equations.

Edit: updated with an MWE directly in the post.

Comment: please don't use external links, make  a small complete example in a code block in the question

Comment: I don't really know how I could make a small example in this case, since the problem occurs only when there's enough text to fill a page, and to show it happening in every case I need several pages worth of text.

Comment: you can use packages such a lipsum to generate dummy text. your question is archived here forever and will not make sense if that external project changes. That said, you get warnings from caption package I would start by removing that

Comment: Ok, but should I post the whole ieeeconf.cls file as well?  It's quite lengthy, and the question won't make sense without that either.

Comment: You can link to that file instead on their website, ieeeconf might already be installed on TeX Live but if it's not then post a link to the class file

Comment: no, people can find that  (a link to a copy would help)

Comment: But then it might not make sense when that file changes someday!  But I'll do as requested regardless.

Comment: I used the revised question with `\usepackage{showframe}`, but nothing exceeded the margins.  If you want to make sure the image fits indisde the parbox, use [width=\linewidth] instead of [scale=0.315] and add % to the naked braces.